# How can I monitor my Chrome App's process in Windows

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I am trying to use an external process monitoring tool to alert me when my Chrome App dies. Unfortunately, all Chrome Apps seem to run inside their own chrome.exe process so there's no way to differentiate them in the monitoring tool. Is there any way to see which Chrome App is running in which process?

Comment: _"Is there any way to see which Chrome App is running in which process?"_ Manually, or with some specific tool?

Comment: Manually from the command line would be preferable

Answer (score 1):

While this certainly is a manual solution (i.e. you won't be able to easily feed it into other tools), Chrome's built-in Task Manager (accessible via menu or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>) allows you to correlate task (in this case, the App) to the system Process ID.

[image: Task Manager]

Whether it's possible from "outside" or using a command line call is still an open question.

One thing that can help distinguishing the process is that app processes always launch with `--extension-process` command line switch. But that doesn't allow you to tell which app (or extension) it is.

It's possible that if verbose enough logging is enabled, one would be able to parse the proccess ID from the logs.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to do this using **tasklist** and looking for the window title which is set from the app name in **manifest.json**:

```
tasklist /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq MyChromeAppName" | find "chrome.exe"
```

For the purposes of the monitor, I wrapped it in a **node.js** function that the monitor app could use:

```
function chromeAppIsRunning(appName, cb){
    var cmd = 'tasklist /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq ' + appName + '" | find "chrome.exe"';
    childprocess.exec(cmd, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        stdout = (stdout || '').toLowerCase();
        cb(stdout.indexOf('chrome.exe') > -1);    
    });
};
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
chromeAppIsRunning('MyApp', function(exists){
    console.log('MyApp is running:', exists);
});
```

Hope that helps someone else